# Can't use Storage Access Framework in my app

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I created an app a few years ago which had it's own file explorer and does so many processes on selected files. recently I wanted to add ability to write to external storages like SD Cards and Hard drives connected through OTG.
The problem is I can't rewrite the whole project based on DocumentFile structure since it's a very big project and it would take forever for me to update. So I needed to somehow convert the old File methods in a few lines and be done with it. this is what I've added so far :

```
private void getPersistentPermission() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
    startActivityForResult(intent, reqcode_storage);
}
```

and :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == reqcode_storage) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                final int perm_flag = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION |
                        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION;
                grantUriPermission(getPackageName(), uri, perm_flag);
                getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, perm_flag);
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(tag, "something`s wrong !");
    }
}
```

then I try to do something like this :

```
try {
    DocumentFile dfile = DocumentFile.fromFile(file);
    OutputStream os = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(dfile.getUri());
    os.write(some_string.getBytes());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(tag, e.toString());
} finally {
    try {
        os.close();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {}
}
```

I get the "file" using implemented file explorer inside my app. it works for internal storage.
I read so many threads about SAF but somehow I can't get it to work. it always shows this error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Permission denied
```

Can anyone tell me what am I missing here ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. have you found anything yet ?

Comment: not yet. I'm trying to read more stuff about it but it seems that it's very poor documented.